# Pass the name of a component when clicked

Tags: c#, blazor

How would I go about passing the name of a component that is clicked through the onclick handler in Blazor WebAssembly? For example (In this case we'll use a table cell):

InterestingTable.razor

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Second</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td @onclick="@(e => CellClicked(e, ?????))" name1="firstTd"><SomeComponent name2="firstComponent" /></td>
            <td @onclick="@(e => CellClicked(e, ?????))" name1="secondTd"><SomeComponent name2="secondComponent" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

InterestingTableBase.cs

```
protected void CellClicked(MouseEventArgs e, ????) {

        }
```

How would I pass either the string in name1 or name2 into the onclick handler?

Thanks!

Comment: no need for mouseevents?
"@(e => CellClicked(firstid))"

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when a dom event handler is invoked, the this keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered. In Blazor this is not the case. You either have to create a component or if you have to use native elements store the values in the code section so that you can access them in the event handler.

Index.razor:

```
<div name="@myDivName" @onclick="MyHandler2"></div>

<Component Name="Foo" OnClick="MyHandler"></Component>


@code{

    private string myDivName = "foo";

    public void MyHandler2()
    {

    }

    public void MyHandler(string name)
    {

    }

}
```

Component.razor:

```
<div name="@Name" @onclick="()=>OnClick.InvokeAsync(Name)"></div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```